# Change a form in order to use jQuery and avoid the page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, css, forms

I'm trying to change the form tag below in order to use jQuery. Already, clicking the buttons changes the display from rows to columns and vice-versa but I want to avoid the page refresh. I'm really new at jQuery and can't honestly say what my mistakes are when trying to change it myself.

```
<form id="rowsToColumns" action="index.php?main_page=specials&disp_order=1" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="style_changer" value="columns"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Change to Column</button>
</form>

<form id="columnsToRows" action="index.php?main_page=specials&disp_order=1" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="style_changer" value="rows"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Change to Rows</button>
</form>
```

I'm also trying for the buttons to call a different stylesheet upon click. This stylesheet is not needed for the display to change from/to rows/columns as I mentioned above. The actual page is written using php as shown below:

```
<?php $this_page =  zen_href_link($_GET['main_page'], zen_get_all_get_params()); ?>
<div id="style_changer">
    <?php if($current_listing_style == 'rows') {?>
    <form id="rowsToColumns" action="<?php echo $this_page;?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="style_changer" value="columns"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Change to Column</button>
    </form>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <form id="columnsToRows" action="<?php echo $this_page;?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="style_changer" value="rows"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Change to Rows</button>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "how to change a form in order to use jQuery and avoid the page refresh", then the [jquery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) is your friend, as it turns any html form into an ajax-powered one.

Simply follow their instructions and you'll get it working in no time (provided your form already works as is).

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the Default form Submission by preventing the default action on the submit button..

```
 $('button[type=submit]').submit( function(e){

       e.preventDefault(); // Stops the form from submitting 
  });
```

Comment: You would be better attaching the submit event to the form. I believe there is some issues with button types in IE. (not 100% certain on that though)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a very vague method you can use `$.ajax` and take advantage of reading the `<form>`'s pre-existing attributes to decide on submission method and read the elements' values as submissiong data:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
  var $form = $(this);
  // submit the form, but use the AJAX equiv. instead of a full page refresh
  $.ajax({
    'url'     : $form.attr('action'),
    'method'  : $form.attr('type'),
    'data'    : $form.serialize(),
    'success' : function(response){
      // process response (make CSS changes or whatever it is
      // a form submission would normally do)
    }
  });
  // prevent the normal submit and reload behavior as AJAX is now
  // handling the submission
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

However, for this to work you'll need some variation of a stripped-down PHP response just for the purpose of the AJAX request (avoid resending headers, script tags, etc. and just return the raw data that jQuery can use to make a UI decision).